# Use a function to change the contents of the array, i.e. multiply each number in the array by 2

Tags: arrays, c, copy, function-definition

**Question**

> Use your function to change the contents of the array, i.e. multiply each number in the array by 2.
>
> When your function has finished and your program continues in your main(), print the contents of your array in your main().
>
> See if the changes made to the contents of the array in your function can be seen. If not, why?

**Further**

I'm trying to multiply the original array by 2 onto another array. Can anyone spot where I've went wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 5

//function signatures
int getMultiples(int[]);

    

//main function
int main() 
{
    //main variables
    int array[SIZE];
    int multiples[SIZE];

    printf("\nPlease enter 5 numbers into an array.\n");
  

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    
    multiples[] = getMultiples(array);
    
    
    printf("\nThis program will multiply all numbers by 2\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", multiples[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int getMultiples(int arr[]) 
{
    //function variables
    int i;
    int multiples[SIZE];
    
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        multiples[i] = arr[i] * 2;
    }

    return multiples[];
}
```

Comment: It's usually best to include the error message you're getting, or include the wrong output and the expected output.

Comment: "*I'm trying to multiply the original array by 2 onto another array.*" -- Why?  That does not seem to be what the assignment is asking of you.  "Change the contents of the array" is quite a different thing from creating a new array with contents based on the original array.  I am quite sure, based on the other prompts in the assignment text, that anything related to creating or populating a new array inside your function is ancillary to the task assigned to you.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
multiples[] = getMultiples(array);
```

is syntactically and semantically invalid. This construction `multiples[]` is wrong and arrays do not have the assignment operator.

Also the definition of the function `getMultiples` is also wrong.

Again this statement

```
    return multiples[];
```

is invalid.

What you are trying to do is to return the local array

```
    int multiples[SIZE];
```

but the function return type is `int`. At least you needed to declare the return type as `int *`.

But in any case the local array that has automatic storage duration will not be alive after exiting the function.

If to use your approach then the function can look the following way

```
void getMultiples( int a1[], const int a2[], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        a1[i] = 2 * a2[i];
    }
}
```

and in main the function is called like

```
getMultiples( multiples, array, SIZE );
```

Pay attention to that the function definition should not depend on the magic number `SIZE`.

By the way in your assignment there is written

> Use your function to change the contents of the array, i.e. multiply
> each number in the array by 2.

It means that you need to change the source array,

In this case the auxiliary array `multiples` is redundant. The function could be defined the following way

```
void getMultiples( int a[], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        a[i] *= 2;
    }
}
```

and called in main like

```
getMultiples( array, SIZE );
```

Answer (score 0):

You promise to return a single int.

```
int getMultiples(...);
```

You don't:

```
return multiples[];
```

You attempt to assign to a whole array (either a single int or an array....).

```
multiples[] = getMultiples(array);
```

That does not work in C.
And judging from what happens when trying your code, your compiler should have told you.